# Errors - Linting www/js/parse.js

Tags: parse-platform, ionic-framework

I am developing an app using ionic framework. In it i am integrating Parse server API. but when i am running my application i am facing following problem -

```
Linting www/js/parse.js
Errors in file www/js/parse.js
9212:1 -> Unreachable '(' after 'return'. -> (function() {
9265:2 -> Read only. ->  exports = module.exports = _;
```

But parse.js is a SDK file and i can't make any change in it.

Could any one explain me whats wrong with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have downloaded and saved `parse.js` manually to your project. It would be better to manage external libraries with `bower`. For example to install this library execute the next from your project root:

```
bower install parse-sdk
```

This will install `parse-sdk` library in the `www/lib` directory. To add this project dependency to your bower manager, add `--save` to end of the command and it will be saved in the `bower.json`.

Within the `index.html` include the `parse.js` from the `www/lib/parse-js-sdk` location.

Now the linting that is part of your `hooks` directory will not process any files in the `www/lib` directory.

If you still want to do it manually like you did, save all libraries outside the `www/js` directory to avoid the linting. Also consider to include the minified version of the JS file to speed things up.

Answer (score -1):

I recommand to add all `vendors` lib into www/lib directory.

I personnaly then do not had the vendor directory to the jshint tests.

This is configured into the `hooks/before_prepare/02_jshint.js` into variable :

```
var foldersToProcess = [];
```

As you have definied the js dir to be parsed for jshint and added the vendor lib in it, it is processed.

Comment: can the one who downgrade my answer explains me why ?